# Do tensors in the tangent space act on functions and vectors?

Tags: derivatives, differential-geometry, lie-algebras, tangent-spaces, tangent-bundle

I know via isomorphism we may treat the tangent space of a point on a manifold as the vector space of derivations on functions at that point. I.e. we can give the tangent space the basis of partials:
$$
v=v^i \partial_i 
$$

This allows vectors to act on functions, and also on eachother via the Lie bracket.

My question is, for tensor products of the tangent space, can we still act on function or vectors?

For a 2-tensor $T$:
$$
T= T^{ij} \partial_i \otimes \partial_j
$$

Can $T$ be made to act on functions or vectors in an unambiguous way?

Comment: You can always let the tensor product of two derivations act on a pair of functions

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In my opinion, the conceptual way to understand this is by viewing the action of a vector field $\xi$ on a function $f$ as the pairing between $\xi$ and the one-form $df$. In this language this becomes a point-wise question and, multilinear algebra tells you, what you can do canonically with a tensor field. Taking the example of $T=T^{ij}\partial_i\otimes\partial_j$ that you mention, there are several possibilities. As mentioned in the comment of @ziggurism , you can take smooth functions $f$ and $g$ and then form $T(df,dg)=\sum_{i,j} T^{ij}\partial_i(f)\partial_j(g)$. This corresponds to the interpretation of the values of $T$ as a bilinear formson the cotangent spaces. Alternatively, you can view $T$ as a map sending covectors to vectors, so you can associate to $df$ the vector field $T(df,\_)$ which is given by $\sum_j b^j\partial_j$, where $b^j=\sum_iT^{ij}\partial_j(f)$. There are more possibilities in the presence of a Riemannian metric, that you can use to raise and lower indices.

Comment: So it seems that, even with a metric, there is no natural way to act, only reasonable ways to define the action, unless perhaps the tensor is symmetric? I suppose for each tensor product, one could define the 'n'th action of the tensor on the scalar.

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by the terms "action" and "act". You can interpret tangent vectors as defining (linear) maps from smooth functions to real numbers but this is not an action in a mathematical sense. (This would on the one had require some algebraic structure on vectors and on the other hand lead to maps from some space to itself.) The only "real" action that is around here is that the Lie algebra of vector fields acts on the vector space of smooth functions. You can always plug copies of $df$ for one $f$ in to obtain higher order operators, but this is not a true action either.

Comment: By act I mostly meant "operate on'

Comment: In that sense, a $\binom{\ell}k$-tensor field can always be thought of as operating on $\ell$ functions (by plugging in $df_1,\dots df_\ell$) and $k$ vectors (by plugging them in directlyt). This is essentially equivalent to the usual picture of tensor fields as multilinear operators on the appropriate number of vector fields and one-forms, which in addition are linear over smooth functions in each entry.